# I need a glue that won't turn opaque or run

Tags: adhesives

I'm trying to glue something to a rock and need a glue that won't turn cloudy over time. I've spoken to several glue manufacturers to no avail. I have also tried about 6 brands so far and none remain clear even if they were clear before drying. The closest I've gotten is with Elmer's. It dried clear but within 6 months became cloudy. Any suggestions? Thanks for thinking about this. I should also mention I need the glue to stay in a "blob" in certain areas so the paint on the underlying rock surface will show through the well-defined dollop of glue. As I said, I used Elmer's which turned cloudy but it didn't run, so that was half the battle. Sorry I didn't mention this in the first version of my question. I did get some answers one being heat-activated adhesive which I have not tried as yet. I have tried Gorilla Glue (dried cloudy) and Duco Cement (was very runny).

Comment: Welcome! What's the thing that is being glued to the rock, and how firmly does it need to be held on? (If it will get stressed or pulled a lot, weaker transparent glues would not work, for example.) Can you [edit] to add any more information? The more details, the better answers you will get :)

Comment: I'm not offering this as an answer because I don't know if it stays clear over deep time but there is a special glue used in plastic model car making which stays clear even when you accidentally smear it on the car's clear windshield.  It applies and dries transparent.  The bottle I have is called "Clear Parts Cement & Window Maker" by Model Master, Inc.  I bought it at a local hobby shop a couple of years ago and it is still good (and clear)

Comment: Thank you Erica. I added more info which I had left out. No stress will be put on most of the glue as some areas will be "stand-alone" blobs, other areas will have rock-to-rock attachments.

Comment: Hi Henry! I'll try your Clear Parts Cement suggestion if I can find the glue. I did edit my question somewhat if you want to reread it. I have tried Duco Cement but it was way too runny and wouldn't stay in a cohesive blob. It did start out clear though. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: More of an answer for Erica-- I have tried Duco Cement and it stayed clear for at least 2 months but per my added edit info, didn't stay in a well-demarcated area. Thanks for your idea. It was a good one.

Comment: Thanks, these are great details :)

Comment: You didn't mention what you are trying to bond with the glue or adhesive.

Comment: It isn't clear whether the objective is to adhere something to the rock, or embed it in a clear blob of material and it is all stuck to the rock.  Any chance there is a picture of something similar you could post, or describe the objective in more detail?

Answer (score 5):

**Use a clear liquid epoxy resin, construction adhesive, 'Gorilla Glue', or 'Iron Grip' silicone adhesive**:

- > **Liquid epoxy resins** dry clear and hard, bonding stones that may not
  >   fit snugly together. It may make some stones look wet in the area of
  >   application. Since this resin is a liquid, it runs a bit after you
  >   apply it, so it can pool beneath the stones if you use too much. Epoxy
  >   resin works well on stones, both large and small.

  [image: Result of stone glued to stone using epoxy resin]
  <sup>[source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGyGkL7pDdw): smaller scale than what the OP might have in mind, but still a valid example of an end result. Be sure to work safer than the author, though.</sup>

  As per [this site](https://www.resinobsession.com/forums/topic/clear-cloudy-resin/), be sure to warm up the resin before application (though not with a heat gun or similar device), as this may help prevent it from turning cloudy.
  In case of outdoor use, be sure to pick an epoxy that is UV stabilized.
  [Additionally](http://forums.sailinganarchy.com/index.php?/topic/179481-cloudy-chalky-epoxy/), make sure you apply it in a dry environment and protect it from getting wet (also while curing), and don't overmix it. <sup>*</sup>

  **Update: you won't be able to get blobs with epoxy resin, unfortunately.**

The following glues are commonly or regularly used for glueing brick walls together, or glueing stones to a vertical surface.

- > **Construction adhesive**, offered in a caulk-style tube, creates bonds
  >   strong enough to hold larger stones together, such as baseball-style
  >   stones or river rocks around the perimeter of a homemade garden pond.

  Make sure you're using a clear variant.

  <sup>[source](https://www.ehow.com/how_8382380_glue-stones-together.html)</sup>
- '**[Clear Gorilla Glue](https://www.gorillatough.com/product/clear-gorilla-glue/)**' (no affiliation):

  > The strength and versatility you have come to expect from Gorilla Glue
  >   is now available in an easy to use, crystal clear, non-foaming
  >   formula. Clear Gorilla Glue is incredibly strong and is ideal for
  >   indoor and outdoor applications and bonds virtually everything.

  See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSNIzxkD450) for an example of mortar replacement. Mind that the regular unclear version is used.
- '**Iron Grip Adhesive Silicone**' (no affiliation):

  > Made from 100% silicone, GE Iron Grip adhesive works fast on almost
  >   any porous and non-porous surface, including aluminum, steel, PVC,
  >   glass, concrete, fiberglass, polystyrene, plywood, drywall, ceramic,
  >   porcelain, stone, laminate, wood and MDF – indoors and out – all
  >   without any extra surface prep.

  Clear curing. [Here](https://youtu.be/-PRsuAJuVqw?t=54)'s a commercial video, showing the glue used on concrete blocks. As always, check the [reviews](https://www.amazon.com/M90058-Iron-Silicone-Adhesive-Clear/product-reviews/B0763JS2P1/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_top?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews).

<sup>* More useful information on the application of epoxies can be found [here](http://www.oneoceankayaks.com/Epoxresl.htm#blush).</sup>

Comment: I’d give you the bounty but I really wanted to see photos of dry clear glue in use.

Comment: @Stefan They're actually hard to find, excepting commercial videos. Especially of the clear curing ones it is hard to find proper illustrations. I've added some links, though.

Comment: You're right. I decided to post my own photos, after buying some of the glue.

Answer (score 3):

Liquid Nails Clear is a Selleys product made in Australia. We use liquid nails here as an all round building and construction glue, including masonry, metal, timber.

Their technical support people tell me:

“Liquid Nails Clear dries very clear with a clear bond line so you have a mess free bond line (you shouldn't be able to see it unless you look at it with an eagle eye.)”

Their instructions say it resists water, and. "24-48hrs strong bond. Cures in 14 days."

*UPDATE:*

**A test using two bricks**

Given the lack of actual photos (even from Selley's) I have done my own test using two house bricks. As you can see the join uses much more glue than necessary but wanted to test and then show its transparency. I think it passed. This product gets tacky very quickly. It's a glue I would *always* wear latex or other gloves with. (I do not need more chemicals in my body.)

Photo 1: Two bricks glued together using Selley’s Liquid Nails Clear:

[image: Two house bricks glued together with Selley’s Liquid Nails Clear.]

---

Photo 2: One strong joint. "24-48hrs strong bond. Cures in 14 days." (Bricks are not resting on ground by the way).

[image: One strong joint!]

Comment: That is a great idea! I'll give it and other clear nail products a try. Thank you!